# not able to access my local host using system IP

Tags: localhost

My target
my server via http://10.12.135.57:2828/

What I can do now
I can access my server via these two ways:

http://localhost:2828
http://127.0.0.1:2828
IP configuration
Result of `ifconfig | grep inet`

```
inet 10.12.135.57  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.12.135.255
        inet6 fe80::add2:1119:8cdc:cc2a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        inet 10.12.135.57  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Output of `cat /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ravijks-OptiPlex-9020

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
Firewall
$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do, and you're missing some details. What services do you run on port 2828 ? Can you access it from somewhere ? From where do you want to access this ? What did you try already ? Please, if you add this information, also take care of formatting your text, e.g. with code blocks. There is a (?) icon on the top right that will help you with that.

Comment: i want to run firefox browser in particular port with marionette  enable ,so i run the firefox on port no 2828.  i can access the localhost:2828 in the browser(50:{"applicationType":"gecko","marionetteProtocol":3}) but if i want to access the port using system IP i am not able to access.

Comment: You may want to look through [the Issues for this project](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues) and perhaps file a bug report. Based on the information provided, this does not appear to be an Ubuntu-specific issue, but one limited to the GeckoDriver 

Comment: can i configured my local host  to listen on 0.0.0.0?